# Parsing XML file (all nodes) to Dataframe (Pandas)

Tags: xml, pandas, parsing, dataframe, nodes

I have many XML files with diversified structures and with many nodes. And I'd like to put it in a dataframe. Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="3.10">`
        <NFe>
            <infNFe Id="NFe13180204501136000136550010008074201020771818" versao="3.10">
                <ide>
                    <nNF>807420</nNF>            
                </ide>
                <emit>
                    <CNPJ>04501136000136</CNPJ>            
                    <IE>041616740</IE>
                    <CRT>3</CRT>
                </emit>
                <det nItem="1">
                    <prod>
                        <NCM>73170090</NCM>
                        <CFOP>5405</CFOP>               
                    </prod>
                    <imposto>
                        <vTotTrib>38.32</vTotTrib>
                        <ICMS>
                            <ICMS60>                     
                                <vBCSTRet>0.00</vBCSTRet>
                                <vICMSSTRet>0.00</vICMSSTRet>
                            </ICMS60>
                        </ICMS>
                    </imposto>
                </det>
                <det nItem="2">
                    <prod>               
                        <NCM>73170090</NCM>
                        <CFOP>5405</CFOP>               
                    </prod>
                    <imposto>
                        <vTotTrib>66.92</vTotTrib>
                        <ICMS>
                            <ICMS60>                     
                                <vBCSTRet>0.00</vBCSTRet>
                                <vICMSSTRet>2.00</vICMSSTRet>
                            </ICMS60>
                        </ICMS>               
                    </imposto>
                </det>         
            </infNFe>
        </NFe>   
    </nfeProc>
```

---

The output:

```
   nNF   nItem       NCM     vICMSSTRet
807420       1  73170090           0.00
807420       2  73170090           2.00
```

---

I've tried this:

```
import xmltodict

xml_list = []
pathname = './dados/dadosfile/'
for f in os.listdir(pathname):
     with open(pathname + f, 'rb') as arquivo:
         doc = xmltodict.parse(arquivo)
         xml_list.append(doc)
```

However, I don't know how to put a list of dict into a dataframe.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share what you tried so we can help you along your learning curve. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I've tried to use xmltodict and put all files into a list of dict. But I don't know how put list of dict into dataframe.

Comment: Please note SO's formatting key `{}` for code blocks. You do not need to manually include back ticks and `<br/>`.